# Advice on removing nested loops in numpy code including conditions and masked data

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I'm writing a function to calculate the ocean mixed layer but so far the best way I have found includes lots of nested loops, which seems bad and is already slow on my test data. Is there a way of refactoring this bearing in mind that the code also includes conditional checks?

I have a working but slow example using nested loops, and I'd like to speed this up. I've begun by changing to e.g. "notmasked_edges" but already I can't figure out in my head what is happening.

This reads in 3D temperature and salinity (depth, latitude, longitude) and the 1D depth coordinate (depth). It returns the 2D "mixed layer depth" (latitude, longitude)

```py
def mld_sigmat(thetao, so, mid_depths):
    """To make the Sigma-T based MLD, defined here:
    'Experimental and diagnostic protocol for the physical component of the
    CMIP6 Ocean Model Intercomparison Project (OMIP)'
    """

    buoyancy_crit = 0.0003  # m/s2, as defined in paper above

    nk, nj, ni = thetao.shape

    mld = np.ma.masked_all(shape=(nj, ni))

    for jj in range(nj):
        for ii in range(ni):
            edges = np.ma.flatnotmasked_edges(thetao[:, jj, ii])
            if edges is None: continue

            # function_to_calculate_density takes 2 N-dim arrays and a
            # 1D depth coordinate which is the same length as the last
            # dimension of the N-dim arrays
            dens_local = np.ma.masked_all(shape=(nk))
            dens_displaced = np.ma.masked_all(shape=(nk))
            for kk in range(edges[0], edges[1]):
                dens_local[kk] = function_to_calculate_density(thetao[kk, jj, ii], this_so[kk, jj, ii], mid_depths[kk]) + 1e3
                dens_displaced[kk] = function_to_calculate_density(thetao[0, jj, ii], this_so[0, jj, ii], mid_depths[kk]) + 1e3

            buoyancy_change = -9.8 * (dens_displaced - dens_local) / dens_local

            indices = np.where(buoyancy_change > buoyancy_crit)[0]

            if len(indices) == 0:  # Full depth convection (criteria never met)
                mld[jj, ii] = mid_depths[edges[1]]
            elif indices[0] == 0:  # No convection
                mld[jj, ii] = mid_depths[edges[0]]
            else:  # MLD is somewhere in between. Take the depth 1 before and then add the extra bit on
                ddepth = mid_depths[indices[0]] - mid_depths[indices[0]-1]
                dbuoyancy = buoyancy_change[indices[0]] - buoyancy_change[indices[0]-1]
                ddepth_dbuoyancy = ddepth / dbuoyancy
                mld[jj, ii] = mid_depths[indices[0]-1] + ddepth_dbuoyancy * (buoyancy_change[indices[0]] - buoyancy_crit)

    return mld
```

Comment: A good first step is to replace the inner most loops.  In thiscase the `kk` loop.  But `function_to_calculate_density` is unknown and apparently only works with scalar values.  If that can't be changed, there's no hope of removing that loop.

Comment: Okay, thanks. That function can handle arrays. I'll edit the question to reflect that, though I'm not sure if that is the recommended way of dealing with updates